# How to use a .NET CommandArgument as a non-string object?

Tags: c#, .net, events, types

Ok so it appears in the [.NET framework API docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.commandargument.aspx) that the CommandArgument property of the CommandEventArg class is of type 'object' suggesting that I might assign to it something other than a string object yet I get an InvalidCastException using the code below:

[aspx code]

```
...
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# context %>' oncommand='reviewContext' </asp:Button>
...
```

[aspx.cs codebehind code]

```
...
public Enum Context { C1, C2, C3 }

public Context context { get { return Context.C1; } }
...
public void reviewContext (object sender, CommandEventArg e) {    
   if((Context) e.CommandArgument == Context.C1) { /*Do something in context of C1 */}
}
```

Why is it tabu to assign something other than a string to the CommandEventArg property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it needs to render the item in the HTML, if it can't make it a string how can it render.

```
return Context.C1.ToString()
```

This will work fine.

Comment: Thanks Hogan, that makes sense I think...your saying the served HTML has to include some kind of text to postback as part of the button response? So I guess my question is really, "why does the CommandEventArg API say it can be an object?"

Comment: Because all objects should implement ToString()

Comment: Yes, but so do all strings :) so why not just define CommandArgument as a string object instead of a generic object if all event handlers must treat it as a string anyhow...?

Comment: Ah sorry, I did not understand your question.  A CommandArgument is *also* used as a parameter to an event.  That is different that the command argument attribute of button.  Here is the CommandArgument for button -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Ahhh...I see said the blind man as he picked up his hammer and saw. Button.CommmandArgument is then a different beast from CommandEventArgs.CommandArgument...thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your enum, you just can't do it in the HTML side. The HTML side is specifically a string representation of the classes involved. You can, however, assign a function to this databinding event, and return the string representation of what is necessary, so

```
public Context context { get { return Context.C1; } }
```

becomes

```
public string context { get { return Context.C1.ToString(); } }
```

However, in order to use the enums once you're in `reviewContext` you'll need to parse the enum out in order to make the comparison:

```
(Context)Enum.Parse(typeof(Context), "C1");
```

*Note:* You can still use the strings to make the comparison, but that defeats the point of the enum I think.

Comment: Thanks Joel, this is basically what I ended up doing...I guess I thought the ASP.NET engine was going to convert my enum to a string and back on the server but as you demonstrated, doing it myself is no big deal.